# Codeigniter Model extends CI_MODEL

Tags: codeigniter, model

I want to create 2 different models `extends` `CI_Model` in core folder,
for example:

```
class MY_FirsModel extends CI_Model {

}

class MY_SecondModel extends CI_Model {

}
```

Is it possible when using codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Codeigniter's Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html), when extending a core class, you need to give the same name to your class, only changing `CI_` by `MY_`.

When the loader class is fetching all core classes it looks for specific matching names such as `Model`, `Controller`, `Exceptions` and so on. It starts looking by the `application/core` folder, with prefixes `MY_` and then goes to `system/core` if a extended class was not found.

If you need to maintain the names `MY_FirsModel` and `MY_SecondModel`, you can create these models in the `application/libraries` folder and the require these files in the classes you will use them.

```
require_once APPPATH.'libraries/MY_FirsModel.php';
```

and

```
require_once APPPATH.'libraries/MY_SecondModel.php';
```

Comment: The documentation link is broken. The current link is: [Extending Core Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to have it like that way. This will going to work. I read it once on `CI forum` (I don't remember the exact link as it's been long time) that some admins like to use this kind of style but many people are in favor of separating them into 2 different file

Comment: Thanks for your answer but ı get error
Fatal error: Class 'MY_FirsModel' not found in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\sbe.deu.edu.tr\httpdocs\application\models\mod\Modelim.php on line 14
Message: Class 'MY_FirsModel' not found

Comment: This is my code           My folder structur 
Apllication/controllers 
Class home extendes CI_Controller{
Public function prnt(){
$this->load->model(‘model’);
$this->model->prnt();
}
Apllication/models 
Model.php
class Modelim extends MY_FirsModel{
    //put your code here
}
Apllication/core
MY_FirstModel.php 
 class MY_FirsModel extends CI_Model {
    public function prnt() {
          echo "MY_first Model";
     }
}
MY_SecondModel.php

Comment: When I use  MY_Model it is wors  but I change the class name like MY_FAT it dosent  work